# Allowing SQL to reference previous alias in select list

Tags: sql, macros, alias

Let's say I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT
    f1 AS Firstname,
    f2 AS LastName,
    CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName) AS FullName
    CONCAT('Dear ', Fullname, ':') AS Salutation
FROM
    px
```

Notice that the alises of the 1st and 2nd select expressions are referenced in the 3rd and the 4th expression references the third. I would like to add a macro-replacement layer to SQL to allow referencing alises, so that it would resolve something like this:

```
SELECT
    f1 AS Firstname,
    f2 AS LastName,
    CONCAT(f1, ' ', f2) AS FullName
    CONCAT('Dear ', CONCAT(f1, ' ', f2), ':') AS Salutation
FROM
    px
```

My question is whether this seems like a bad idea, or that it could have hidden pitfalls in it? I suppose if both `px` (table reference) had a field called `FullName` and a previous item in the select list also had the alias, it could become ambiguous which one it refers to but in that case, I would just add an order of operations, such that if they exist in both places it would default to one over the other. In the case that there is ambiguity, do you think it would make more sense to default to the field in the table or in the previous select item?

Comment: This mechanism is called lateral column aliasing and depending on implementation could have hidden issues. For instance if column is not deterministic. `SELECT RANDOM() AS c,  c+1` should the RANDOM() first be materialized or evaluated twice.

Comment: As for column name/alias shadowing - [Calculated keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68400263/5070879)

Comment: @LukaszSzozda oh neat -- does Snowflake currently have this feature? Do you know of any other DBMS that do?

Comment: The calculated keyword is supported by SAS only as I am aware

Comment: Another RDBMS that allows to access alias at the same level on SELECT [Amazon Redshift - lateral column alias reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59334543/amazon-redshift-lateral-column-alias-reference)

Comment: @LukaszSzozda in the case of `CALCULATED` would doing `SELET RANDOM() AS c, CALCULATED c+1` only evaluate the `RANDOM()` once?

Comment: The usage of calcululated is to distinguish between actual column from table/view and alias `SELECT c, c+1 AS c, calculated c FROM tab`

Comment: @LukaszSzozda got it, and does it evaluate the alias each time or only once and materialize it?